# Copying multiple columns from one SQL table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to copy some columns from one table to another table at the same time. This is my query :

```
INSERT INTO [db_new].[dbo].[Element](Number, ElementNumber)
    SELECT (NUMBER, ELEMENTNUMBER) 
    FROM [db_old].[dbo].[ELEMENTS]
```

I get this error for this query :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

How can I safely copy multiple columns at the same time? Thanks.

Comment: ... SELECT NUMBER, ELEMENTNUMBER ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO [db_new].[dbo].[Element] (Number, ElementNumber)
SELECT NUMBER
    ,ELEMENTNUMBER
FROM [db_old].[dbo].[ELEMENTS]
```

Answer (score 4):

For this operation you need use select as a standard query as below

```
INSERT INTO [db_new].[dbo].[Element](Number,ElementNumber)
    SELECT NUMBER, ELEMENTNUMBER FROM [db_old].[dbo].[ELEMENTS]
```